# Issue with Swift Completion Handler Syntax

Tags: xcode, swift

I have the following function provided in an open source piece of code:

```
public static func login(displayViewController: ViewController, completion: SimpleAPIResponse<Session> -> Void) {
        authorize(displayViewController, completion: { result in
            if let session = result.response.result {
                session.getToken({ result in
                    Soundcloud.session = result.response.result
                    completion(result)
                })
            }
            else {
                completion(result)
            }
        })
    }
```

For the life of me, I keep getting an insert "," error after "->", when that's obviously just the compiler wigging out due to a syntax issue.. when executing the following code:

```
Session.login(self, completion: SimpleAPIResponse<Session> -> Void)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Session.login(self, completion: {(result: SimpleAPIResponse<Session>) -> Void in
        //Insert completion code
```

})

When using a completion handler, I guess I forgot to actually.. ya know.. use a completion block with code to execute upon completion.

Comment: if you answered yourself, please mark this question as answered.